# jsone encode output

Tags: json

hey guys lets say i got this command:

```
var url = 'http://www.site.com/verifynew.php?txn=e0100074f26e46742d8f&callback=?';
$.getJSON(url,  function (response) {window.location=response.redirect;});
```

the output i think i need on that verify php page should be something like:

```
?({'redirect':'something'})
```

now on my php page i got this code:

```
$url = $obj->url;
$d = array("redirect" => $url); 
print json_encode($d);
```

and its outputting:

```
?({"redirect":"http:\/\/google.com"})
```

print $url shows http://google.com so i dont know where the 2 \ are from

Comment: These are escaping slashes for the /'s. You could try to disable PHP magic quotes or wrap stripslashes() around json_encode(), however it's probably best to just leave it there, since whatever destination you're sending that JSON data to will probably parse them out.

Answer (score 0):

That output is valid JavaScript and JSONP.  That is an acceptable way to escape a URL in JavaScript, and will execute fine.

Answer (score 0):

The two \ are literal escapes for the / character. See the sidebar on http://www.json.org/

Also see this discussion: http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/EscapingExamples